# Interior of a subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: general-topology

I want to find the interior of the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ $$A = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \text{ is rational}\}$$

I guess that $\operatorname{Int} A = \emptyset$.

To find the interior, I want show that if $(x, y)$ be an arbitrary point of $A$, then there does not exist any neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ such that $U \subset A$. And to do that I want to show $U$ be a nbd of $(x,y)$ such that $U \subset A$, then it is a contradiction. Hence $\operatorname{Int} A = \emptyset$. I think the density property of irrational would help.

But I can can not use it. Please help me

Comment: Can you show that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ there is a number $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \times (y-\varepsilon, y+\varepsilon) \subseteq U \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Will the following work....Let $(x, y) \in A$, and let $r>0$, then $(x-r, x+r) \times \{y\} \subset B_d((x,y),r) \subset A$...? Then since $(x-r, x+r) $ contains a irrational, it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Do you know what an open map is? And do you know that projection maps are open? That provides an easy answer using the fact that $\operatorname{int} \mathbb Q=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Dog_69 I know that $f$ is open map: if $U$ is open then $f(U)$ is open...Particulary projection map is an open map. but how should I proceed further in the case?

Comment: @user454229 Open maps satisfy the following relation: $$f(\operatorname{int}A)\subseteq \operatorname{int} f(A).$$ In your case $f$ is the projection onto the first factor and $A$ is your set $A$. Do you see how to continue?

Comment: @user454229 : That works.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you canot use the density of the irrationals, use the fact that every open ball in $\Bbb R^2$ has uncountably many elements.

Comment: $\ldots\,$and therefore those elements cannot all be in $\mathbb Q^2.$ But you do you know they're not all in $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb R \text{?}$ It seems as if more than just cardinality alone is needed for that. $\qquad$