# Interior of $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \text{ is rational}\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I want to find the interior of the following subset of $A = \mathbb{R}^2$ $$\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \text{ is rational}\}$$

I guess that $\text{Int } A = \emptyset$.

MY ATTEMPT:

Let $(x, y)$ be a point in $A$ and $r>0$. Then $(x -r, x+r) \times \{y\} \subset B_d((x,y), r) \subset A$. Now due to density property of irrationals $(x-r, x+r)$  contains an irrational number, which follows that $B_d((x,y), r) \not\subset A$. Therefore, $(x,y) \not\in \text{Int } A$, hence $\text{Int } A = \emptyset$.

Please check my solution. Is it correct?

Comment: For benefit of others I will add a link to the original question (which wasn't a solution verification): [Interior of a subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203510)

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: This should have been an edit of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. In general, the following is true.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $A \subset X$ have empty interior. Then, $A \times B$ has empty interior for any subset $B \subset Y$.

*Proof.* Any basis element of $X \times Y$ is of the form $U \times V$ for open subsets $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$. Since $A$ has empty interior, it follows that $A \times B$ cannot contain any such nonempty basis element.  $\Box$

From this, your particular question follows with $X = Y = B = \Bbb R$ and $A = \Bbb Q$.